# Multichild Expandable list android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to create a expandable list view that contains child layout inside the child layout i want the sub-child layout as like below..

[image]

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java?av=f