# How to add child view to an excisting child view in Expandable ListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have successfully implemented Expandable ListView in my project. The response I got from the server has subcategories within subcategory. I need to show that also. I tried but only the main subcategory get displayed. Is there any way to display this in hierarchy and maintain the click event for all subcategory.
It should be like this.

```
Parent1
  category1
  category2
  category3
      Subcategory1
      Subcategory2
          Sub-subcategory1
  category4
Parent2
  category1
  category2......
```

Comment: did you need something like `treeView`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128106/multichild-expandable-list-android

Comment: Shayan, the link you provide helps.

Answer (score 0):

onGetChildView()  create another expandableView to get 3rd level list, if you want more, do it again in the sub expandable list, you can manage all click events.

You also need to implement onMeasure to calculate correct height for the sub categories for 3rd, 4th level.